# About the fate of malloc()ed arrays of arrays

Tags: objective-c, opengl, free, malloc, dynamic-arrays

my first question on Stackoverflow.

Let me start with a bit of code.  It's a bit repetitive so I'm going to cut out the parts I repeat for different arrays (feel free to ask for the others).  However, please ignore the code in preference to answering the Qs at the bottom.  Firstly: thank you to answerers in advance.  Secondly: the freeing of data.

```
@implementation ES1Renderer

GLfloat **helixVertices;
GLushort **helixIndices;
GLubyte **helixColors;

- (void)freeEverything
{
    if (helixVertices != NULL)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < alphasToFree / 30 + 1; i++)
            free(helixVertices[i]);
        free(helixVertices);
    }

    if (helixIndices != NULL)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < alphasToFree / 30 + 1; i++)
            free(helixIndices[i]);
        free(helixIndices);
    }

    if (helixColors != NULL)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < alphasToFree / 30 + 1; i++)
            free(helixColors[i]);
        free(helixColors);
    }
}
```

(I will get to the calling of this in a moment).  Now for where I malloc() the arrays.

```
- (void)askForVertexInformation
{
    int nrows = self.helper.numberOfAtoms / 300;
    int mrows = [self.helper.bonds count] / 300;

    int alphaCarbonRows = [self.helper.alphaCarbons count] / 30;

    helixVertices = malloc(alphaCarbonRows * sizeof(GLfloat *) + 1);
    helixIndices = malloc(alphaCarbonRows * sizeof(GLfloat *) + 1);
    helixColors = malloc(alphaCarbonRows * sizeof(GLfloat *) + 1);

    for (int i=0; i < alphaCarbonRows + 1; i++)
    {
        helixVertices[i] = malloc(sizeof(helixVertices) * HELIX_VERTEX_COUNT * 3 * 33);
        helixIndices[i] = malloc(sizeof(helixIndices) * HELIX_INDEX_COUNT * 2 * 3 * 33);
        helixColors[i] = malloc(sizeof(helixColors) * HELIX_VERTEX_COUNT * 4 * 33);

    }
    [self.helper recolourVerticesInAtomRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self.helper.alphaCarbons count]) withColouringType:CMolColouringTypeCartoonBlue forMasterColorArray:helixColors forNumberOfVertices:HELIX_VERTEX_COUNT difference:30]; 

    self.atomsToFree = self.helper.numberOfAtoms;
    self.bondsToFree = [self.helper.bonds count];
    self.alphasToFree = [self.helper.alphaCarbons count];
}
```

Finally, the bit which calls everything (this is a separate class.)

```
- (void)loadPDB:(NSString *)pdbToLoad
{
    if (!self.loading)
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        [self.renderer freeEverything];
        [renderer release];
        ES1Renderer *newRenderer = [[ES1Renderer alloc] init];
        renderer = [newRenderer retain];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; // need to stop the new renderer animating too!
        [self.renderer setDelegate:self];
        [self.renderer setupCamera];
        self.renderer.pdb = nil;
        [renderer resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
        [newRenderer release];

        NSInvocationOperation *invocationOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setup:) object:pdbToLoad];
        [self.queue addOperation:invocationOperation];
        [invocationOperation release];
    }
}

- (void)setup:(NSString *)pdbToLoad
{
    self.loading = YES;

    [helper release];
    [renderer.helper release];
    PDBHelper *aHelper = [[PDBHelper alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pdbToLoad];
    helper = [aHelper retain];
    renderer.helper = [aHelper retain];
    [aHelper release];

    if (!resized)
    {
        [self.helper resizeVertices:11];
        resized = YES;
    }

    self.renderer.helper = self.helper;

    [self.helper setUpAtoms];
    [self.helper setUpBonds];

    if (self.helper.numberOfAtoms > 0)
        [self.renderer askForVertexInformation];
    else
    {           
        // LOG ME PLEASE.
    }

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeProgressBar) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimation) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    self.renderer.pdb = pdbToLoad;

    self.loading = NO;
}
```

What I'm doing here is loading a molecule from a PDB file into memory and displaying it on an OpenGL view window. The second time I load a molecule (which will run `loadPDB:` above) I get the Giant Triangle Syndrome and Related Effects... I will see large triangles over my molecule.

However, I am releasing and reallocating my PDBHelper and ES1Renderer every time I load a new molecule.  Hence I was wondering:

1. whether the helixVertices, helixIndices and helixColors which I have declared as class-wide variables are actually re-used in this instance.  Do they point to the same objects?

2. Should I be setting all my variables to NULL after freeing?  I plan to do this anyway, to pick up any bugs by getting a segfault, but haven't got round to incorporating it.
3. Am I even right to malloc() a class variable? Is there a better way of achieving this? I have no other known way of giving this information to the renderer otherwise.

Comment: This question is 4 pages long. A more concise question is more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that - for my first question, I was aware (from reading many questions on here) that often lack-of-supply-of-code is more frustrating than too much code, but I appear to have overdone it.  Trying to find the edit button.

Comment: The question isn't necessarily a problem, but if you could reduce the example code to a handful of lines demonstrating your question, it'd be a lot easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer your general questions.  There's too much stuff in there.  However, this caught my eye:

```
[helper release];
[renderer.helper release];
PDBHelper *aHelper = [[PDBHelper alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pdbToLoad];
helper = [aHelper retain];
renderer.helper = [aHelper retain];
[aHelper release];
```

I think this stuff possibly leaks.  It doesn't make sense anyway.

If renderer.helper is a retain or copy property, do not release it.  It already has code that releases old values when it is assigned new values.  Also do not retain objects you assign to it.

You have alloc'd aHelper, so there's no need to retain it again.  The above code should be rewritten something like:

```
[helper release];
helper = [[PDBHelper alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pdbToLoad];
renderer.helper = helper;
```

---

Also, I think your helix malloced arrays should probably be instance variables.  As things stand, if you have more than one ES1Renderer, they are sharing those variables.

Comment: Ah! They are sharing the variables.  I just noticed the fact that they are called "class variables", and therefore shared by the class. (slow me).  You have pretty much answered my main question, thanks!
<p>
As for the [retain]/[release] stuff, I thought I wasn't accessing the accessor method because I didn't put "self." in front of it, and therefore had to do the [retain] message myself.  However, your code looks much tidier and I will adopt it - thank you :)

Comment: @Helen:  `renderer.helper = helper` *is* using the accessor method.  It's the same as `[renderer setHelper: helper]`.  You need to use `self.` to access the object's *own* properties. i.e. `self.helper = foo` is the same as `[self setHelper: foo]`.  In your code (and mine) we are setting the instance variable directly.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!  I should sleep more often.